# Loop not working when I try to traverse a Simple XML Object

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm trying to loop through the results from the Last.fm API but it's not working.

```
function get_url($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $content;
}
$xml = get_url('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.search&album=kid%20a&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026');
$doc = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$albums = $doc->results->albummatches;
foreach($albums as $album){
    echo $album->album->name;
}
```

This just shows the first album. If I change the code within the foreach loop to `echo $album->name;` it shows nothing at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using this :

```
$albums = $doc->results->albummatches;
foreach($albums->album as $album){
    echo $album->name . '<br />';
}
```

This seems to get the list of albums names.

To make things short, instead of looping over `$doc->results->albummatches`, you have to loop over `$doc->results->albummatches->album`.

And, then, inside the loop, `$album` corresponds to the current album ; so, you can use `$album->name`